# Poker Practice - Preflop All In

Tags: online

Fairly new player here - I've been using an online practice game (vs AI) as a tool to start off with.  In their games, if someone goes all-in before the flop and no one calls them on it, that player is then out of the game/loses all their chips.  Is this true of other poker games or is it just a glitch of the practice system?  Sorry for the extremely newbie question!

Comment: What software is this?

Answer (score 4):

That sounds like an error within the software; real poker games have nothing similar to that function.

Comment: So usually if you go all in preflop and then have the only hand, then the chips are yours?

Comment: Your _all-in_ is going to win the hand either called by a worse non-improved hand or not called at all. It sounds like a software's glitch. Wondering how they missed that as it pretty basic 8)

Answer (score 1):

No, that's ridiculous of course. Either you misunderstand what's happening or that software is worthless.

Answer (score -1):

A real Normal player with there functionality won't go all in without the flop.
Which game do you have played ?

I really recommend Zynga Poker in facebook for begginers :)